# (locally Holder) + (locally Lipschitz) $\Longrightarrow$ Continuity?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f = f(x,y)$ be locally Holder continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$, i.e. given $(z_1,z_2)$ in the domain of definition, there exists a neighborhood $U$ such that for any $(x_1,x_2)$, $(y_1,y_2) \in U$ then $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le H|x_1 - y_1|^{\theta} + L|x_2 - y_2|, \qquad \theta \in (0,1).$$ Is it true that $f$ is continuous?

My opinion is that it is trivially true given that the continuity is a local concept. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the inequality you wrote trivially implies continuity.

A tiny effort is required to obtain the inequality you wrote from the assumptions "locally Hölder continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$", since each of these assumptions refers to the behavior of $f$ when one of its variables is being held constant. This tiny effort amounts to using the triangle inequality.